# How to force button and select on the same line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, select

I have a form on my site and I want to put a button and select tag on the same line, but it keep causing line break. I've tried a button instead and it works totally fine one after another on a line. I am using bootstrap 3.

```
<div class="panel-footer" style ="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="width:100px; margin:4px;">send</button> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="width:100px; margin:4px;">send</button> 
    <select class="form-control" style = "width:100px; margin:4px;">
        <option value="volvo">Math</option>
        <option value="saab">History</option>
        <option value="opel">English</option>
        <option value="audi">Gymnastics</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

There is enough space for like 4 more selects on the line.

Comment: I just copy paste this code and its showing two buttons and a select box in same line. I can't repro this issue. But you can try 'float: left' option in css for button and select box.

Comment: it is because the other divs it's already in probably, also float for both controls made the panel shrink but the control stay partially outside. @anuja

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` on the select and the button

Answer (score 0):

You can put the select and button inside a table.

Works for me. Simple really.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<select>
<option value="1">Value 1</option>
<option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Choose number">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Using tables for styling / layout is bad practice and problematic, instead, use CSS, using HTML elements for styling breaks the separation of concerns best practice. HTML is for structure, CSS for styling. Hope that makes sense and is constructive.

Comment: Thank you for this quick fix until I can get the CSS/HTML people to work on it. This allows me to demo the project until the proper fix is made.