# Row of HTML elements. Button not staying on same row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a project using Bootstrap as my front end framework.
I've got a vertical scrollable card with some items in it. Each row is composed of the following code:

```
<p>
 <span>
  <span style="display: inline-block; width: 100px;">
   <strong><?php echo $clientSiteDemandRow['dayOfWeek']; ?></strong>
  </span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 70px;">
  <i class="fa fa-clock"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $clientSiteDemandRow['shiftStart']; ?>
 </span>
 <span style="display: inline-block; width: 100px;">
  <?php echo $hours; ?>&nbsp;Hours
 </span>
 <span style="display: inline-block; width: 30px;" style="white-space: nowrap;">
  <form action="" method="POST">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="deleteSiteDemand" name="deleteSiteDemand" value="<?php echo $clientSiteDemandRow['id']; ?>">Delete</button>
  </form>
 </span>
 </span>
</p>
```

[image: Example]

As you can see the first row renders how I want it, but on the subsequent rows the 'Delete' button wraps to the next line. It's not a space issue as there is plenty of room for the button.

How can I keep that button on the same row? All my google searches result in inline forms and not necessarily my situation.

I have tried these:
[How to force button and select on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412869/how-to-force-button-and-select-on-the-same-line)

I have tried using display: inline; and display: inline-block; on the outermost span to no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all don't wrap your elements in a `p` tag, use `div`. `id` should be unique. All your Delete buttons have same `id`

NB: For your scenario I would just using Bootstrap grid layout.

Looking at your code, try removing the wrapping `p` tag with a `div`

`form` inside a `p` is not semantically correct even though it works in most cases. In some scenarios it behave weird . As per [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/p.html) only [phrasing contents](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/common-models.html#common.elem.flow) are allowed inside a `p` tag.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
 <span>
  <span style="display: inline-block; width: 100px;">
   <strong>Monday</strong>
  </span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 70px;">
  <i class="fa fa-clock"></i>&nbsp; 8.00 
 </span>
 <span style="display: inline-block; width: 100px;">
  &nbsp;Hours
 </span>
 <span style="display: inline-block; width: 30px;" style="white-space: nowrap;">
  <form action="" method="POST">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="deleteSiteDemand" name="deleteSiteDemand" value="<?php echo $clientSiteDemandRow['id']; ?>">Delete</button>
  </form>
 </span>
 </span>
</div>

<div>
 <span>
  <span style="display: inline-block; width: 100px;">
   <strong>Monday</strong>
  </span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 70px;">
  <i class="fa fa-clock"></i>&nbsp; 8.00 
 </span>
 <span style="display: inline-block; width: 100px;">
  &nbsp;Hours
 </span>
 <span style="display: inline-block; width: 30px;" style="white-space: nowrap;">
  <form action="" method="POST">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="deleteSiteDemand" name="deleteSiteDemand" value="<?php echo $clientSiteDemandRow['id']; ?>">Delete</button>
  </form>
 </span>
 </span>
</div>
<div>
 <span>
  <span style="display: inline-block; width: 100px;">
   <strong>Monday</strong>
  </span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 70px;">
  <i class="fa fa-clock"></i>&nbsp; 8.00 
 </span>
 <span style="display: inline-block; width: 100px;">
  &nbsp;Hours
 </span>
 <span style="display: inline-block; width: 30px;" style="white-space: nowrap;">
  <form action="" method="POST">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="deleteSiteDemand" name="deleteSiteDemand" value="<?php echo $clientSiteDemandRow['id']; ?>">Delete</button>
  </form>
 </span>
 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Holy crap, you're a genius. I never thought change a p to a div would have made that effect. This whole time I was under the assumption that a div would make it worse. This solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @David - `form` inside a `p` is not semantically correct even though it works in most cases. In some scenarios it behave weird . As per [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/p.html) only [phrasing contents](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/common-models.html#common.elem.flow) are allowed inside a `p` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<div class="parent">
<children />...
</div>

.parent {
  display = flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a table

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">



<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <strong>Day Of Week</strong>
    </th>
    <th>
      Shift Start
    </th>
    <th>
      Hours
    </th>
    <th>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <strong>Monday</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
      08:00
    </td>
    <td>
      8 Hours
    </td>
    <td>
      <form action="" method="POST">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah, I could do a table but I'm trying to avoid it. I've always felt that using table to style a page that already uses CSS is just bad form.

Comment: If you can't use a table for obviously tabular data, when can you?

Comment: I hear you. I've been criticized heavily in the past for using tables for design and alignment purposes. Called it Web 1.0

Comment: Your use case is the dictionary definition of a table.